# Bitrix VM + mailcow

Tags: nginx, сервер, docker, email, devops

Есть vps с BitrixVM, необходимо на ней же развернуть почтовый сервер. Использую mailcow, все замечательно разворачивается но конфликтует с nginx который не из контейнера docker,можно ли как то разрешить проблему, чтобы и docker контейнер nginx и локально установленный на сервер nginx работали на одних портах

Answer (score 0):

**У контейнера nginx прокиньте во вне другие порты и используйте их**.

Для команды docker run используйте опцию --publish (-p).

Если используете docker-compose, то пропишите опцию ports в docker-compose.yaml